# XCode message/warning Can’t show file for current stack frame

Tags: xcode, stack, frame, automatic-ref-counting

When running my app at some point xcode gives me the following message and the app crashes.

> Can’t show file for current stack frame.
>
> The file /SourceCache/arclite_host/arclite-4/source/arclite.m does not exist on the file system.

Does anyone know how to fix this?